# Кнопки в inlinekeyboard с длинным текстом

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Формирую список продуктов, который записывается БД и в боте можно вызвать inline клавиатуру, где каждый продукт на отдельной кнопке для дальнейшего редактирования/удаления. Но при добавлении длинного текста (в БД он добавляется корректно) и вызове клавиатуры получаю Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID. Читал в документации, что callback_data - 1-64 байта, но сталкивался с ботами, где при добавлении подобных текстов все работает.

Пример клавиатуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код для "вычеркивания" продукта из списка:

```
    elif 'edit_product' in call.data:
        product = call.data.replace('edit_product ', '')
        if '✖ ' in product:
            for i in range(len(list_of_products)):
                if list_of_products[i] == product:
                    list_of_products[i] = product.replace('✖ ', '')

            db.db_update_call(call, list_of_products)
            # show alert
            clear_product = product.replace('✖ ', '')
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text=f'{clear_product} unticked')
        else:
            cross_product = '✖ ' + product
            for i in range(len(list_of_products)):
                if list_of_products[i] == product:
                    list_of_products[i] = cross_product

            db.db_update_call(call, list_of_products)

            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text=f'{product} ticked')

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        products = []
        for product in list_of_products:
            btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{product}', callback_data=f'edit_product {product}')
            products.append(btn)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='⬅', callback_data='back')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='delete')
        keyboard.add(*products)
        keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                      reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Храните в callback_data id на продукты, раз места в 64 **байта** не хватает, например `edit_product#1234`

Comment: О, отличная идея, спасибо, буду думать как это реализовать

Comment: @gil9red Хотя тут несколько вопросов возникает, я названия продукта подтягиваю из call.data (product = call.data.replace('edit_product ', '')), а если я буду делать через id продукта, то соответственно название будет некорректным. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Пусть у продукта будет id и название, нужно будет id вытаскивать из `data` и по id найти продукт и работать с ним, например, показывая название

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря советам [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red) реализовал так:

```
    elif 'edit_product' in call.data:
        product_id = call.data.replace('edit_product ', '')
        if '✖ ' in dict_lop[product_id]:
            for i in range(len(list_of_products)):
                if list_of_products[i] == dict_lop[product_id]:
                    list_of_products[i] = dict_lop[product_id].replace('✖ ', '')
            dict_lop = {str(product_id): product for product_id, product in
                        enumerate(list_of_products, 1)}
            db.db_update_call(call, list_of_products)
            # show alert
            clear_product = dict_lop[product_id].replace('✖ ', '')
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False, text=f'{clear_product} unticked')
        else:
            cross_product = '✖ ' + dict_lop[product_id]
            for i in range(len(list_of_products)):
                if list_of_products[i] == dict_lop[product_id]:
                    list_of_products[i] = cross_product
            dict_lop = {str(product_id): product for product_id, product in
                        enumerate(list_of_products, 1)}
            db.db_update_call(call, list_of_products)

            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                                      text=f'{dict_lop[product_id]} ticked')

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        products = []
        for product_id, product in dict_lop.items():
            btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{product}', callback_data=f'edit_product {product_id}')
            products.append(btn)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='⬅', callback_data='back')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='delete')
        keyboard.add(*products)
        keyboard.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                                      reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Первое время просто в самом начале @bot.callback_query_handler формировал словарь dict_lop на основе данных из БД, но получал ошибку Bad Request: message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message". Поэтому решил обновлять словарь после каждого обновления БД. (не знаю на сколько это корректно, но работает), если у вас есть предложения по оптимизации буду рад их прочитать.